# What kind of tool can I use to tighten a faucet bolt in a tight place?

Tags: kitchens, tools, faucet

I am trying to tighten a kitchen faucet bolt (7/16 inch) in a very tight spot. Please refer to the picture.

Standard size wrenches don't fit well enough for me to turn it.  I've used a stubby wrench but I can't get any leverage because of the tight spot.  I bought a set of flex head rachet wrenches, but they keep slipping off.  I also tried a basin wrench, but it keeps slipping off and is very hard to attach.

Do you recommend any other tools that would work?  Would an offset wrench work or an adjustable flex head wrench work?  I just don't want to keep collecting tools that I won't use!

Thanks for your help :)

[image: The bolt is right under the bracket]

Comment: That bolt looks a little rusty. Can you either clean it or replace it? Are the threads clean? This is a minor point but its easier to work on clean parts in tight spaces than on dirty parts in tight spaces!

Comment: I assume that by now you got the nut off.  If not, post here and I'll give you my two cents worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may work is very deep socket. There is a chance the bolt may extend thru the socket. If that happens clamp onto the socket with a pair of vice grips to tighten the last few turns.

Comment: I like the deep socket idea.  Thanks!  I tried the basin wrench but it kept slipping off too...I'll update the question to put that info in!

Comment: There is a technique to a basin wrench.  You have to flip the head to tighten or loosen.  But it still can be difficult.   A plastic deep socket tool is included from the manufacturer in a recent faucet I purchased.

Comment: Right, I have a plastic deep socket too.  But I couldn't get enough torque without it slipping off.

Answer (score 10):

I think your options are either a Basin Wrench
[image]
or an extra deep socket
[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Where can I get the deep socket?  I'm drawing blanks on Amazon...any particular

Comment: That particular pic is from Home Depot, but a google for 'extra deep socket' seems to bring up many hits, including amazon.

Comment: Thanks! Found it on Amazon.  Are these really hollow enough to reach the bolt?

Comment: @DIYNewbie They're called [mixer tap spanners](https://www.bunnings.com.au/haron-mixer-tap-spanner-kit_p4900083) here, and are designed specifically for this purpose. Should be more than enough depth for that bolt. But if you're concerned you can look at the height specs in the Amazon listing - they should be hollow all the way through.

Answer (score 9):

I think that is a standard application for a "crows foot" wrench.

[image]

Comment: The OP might benefit from a photo?

Comment: Sorry @blacksmith37, I duplicated your answer. I will delete mine but add the photo to yours!

Comment: @JimmyFix-it -- no, no, don't delete your answer!  Great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 7):

The standard tool for these under-sink nuts is a tube spanner:

[image: Tube Spanner Set]

The tube is long enough to go over the thread and the holes take the handle which can be shifted side to side when you're in a confined space.

I had a faucet bolt that kept coming loose that I would keep tightening as best I could with a shifter (and grazed knuckles). Once I got a tube spanner, I tightened it once and it's been good ever since.

Answer (score 3):

If you can almost get that nut with a proper wrench, but the nut is just not long enough... there is a cheaper option than buying a tool for this.

Just use a coupling nut

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are 11 mm nuts, and really the only good way that I've found to tighten them is with a standard **12-point** angled box end wrench.

[image]

Get the 12-point box end on the nut and turn in 30-degree turns. It will take a while but it goes in easily. In fact, be careful not to overtighten, as the nut is typically copper and the bolt is also a soft metal. These metals are used because the area is extremely corrosion prone.

Note that the **7/16 inch** specified in the question is *not* the right size, and may explain the slippage that the OP experienced. The right size is **11 mm**.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try to get this in a off set stubby form.  It's just really hard to reach up their and get torque.

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to use a piece of wood to space the mounting plate off and thus take up the length of the bolt. This also spreads the load from the tap over a greater area on the sink.

With the length of the bolt taken up I was then able to tighten/loosen it with a normal depth socket.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try a [Ridgid Sink & Faucet Installer Tool](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-Faucet-and-Sink-Installer-Tool-27018/100595073). I've seen them used a few times and they make most aspects of the install much more quick.