# Removing faucet from kitchen

Tags: plumbing, faucet, removal, kitchen-counters

I have a faucet that leaks at the valve, and I would like to remove that faucet to replace it with a new one.

The trouble is that it is mounted tightly between the wall and the sink, so there is very little space to work with.

I would like to avoid having to get the entire sink removed.

How would I remove this faucet?

The view from below:

[image]

The view from top:

[image]

It is unclear to me what I should be twisting.

Do I twist that large open ring? Against what? Faucet-base? Faucet-body?

And in which direction do I turn it?

Do I need a special tool?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, you don't need to remove the sink to remove the faucet.

Follow this sequence of steps:

1. Turn off both the Hot & Cold shutoff valves leading to the sink
2. Unscrew the flexible braided hoses from the faucet
   You may need 2 wrenches for this job - one to turn the nut on the flex hose and another to hold the brass piece on the end of the copper pipe in place (to prevent the copper pipe twisting)
   [image]
3. Disconnect the flexible hose leading to the pull-down faucet outlet or separate sprayer
   Different manufacturers have their own ways of doing this, but it'll probably involve unscrewing a threaded plastic coupling of some sort
   [image]
4. Loosen & remove the small brass nut which holds the large open-sided ring in place
   [image]
5. Lift the old faucet out of the sink

To install the new faucet, reverse the steps, paying particular attention to the part of step 2 where you avoid twisting the thin copper pipes.

Refer to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/127108/what-kind-of-tool-can-i-use-to-tighten-a-faucet-bolt-in-a-tight-place/127109) for some tool suggestions - particularly the 'Basin Wrench' which makes the job of turning those nuts a little easier in the tight space you have to work in.
You should expect this job to be a bit of a P-in-the-A ... it's one I always dread - although your old faucet looks nice & clean & not corroded underneath which makes the job a little easier.

Comment: I think he may need a special tool to remove that brass nut. Might be as simple as a deep well socket but I don't think you can remove with pliers or a wrench.

Comment: Your guide did the job! Once the plastic clip was released, the spray-line came out. The threaded pipe was short enough that I could put one of those pipe-wrenches over it, and remove the brass nut. The hardest part was working in a tiny space like that! Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @Bram, it's the classic plumber's lament - Richard Trethewey :V

Comment: @user3481644, I bought one of those useful tools 20 years ago. I have yet to find a tight situation where there was enough space to use it :-(. Slip-joint pliers have saved the day for me.

Comment: @grahamj42 I stand corrected - my description is NOT a "sink" wrench, it is a "basin" wrench.

Comment: The special tool needed is a "BASIN wrench", it is a long shaft with a "twist bar" at one that slides to either end, and a "claw" at the other end that can flip to make it tighten or loosen. It might not be necessary, but it helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

So, OP did succeed using the straightforward instructions of @brhans. But - if the nuts had been more tightly fastened, he may not have been so lucky. So, here are suggestions of two tools which *may* help in this situation.

1. **[Vise-grip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locking_pliers)**: when using two wrenches, lets you just hold it instead of applying pressure - it applies its own pressure on the gripped object.

   [image]

   Caveat: may itself be a little tricky to use at an angle in that narrow space.
2. **Limited-clearance adjustable wrench**: Most [adjustable spanners/wrenches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjustable_spanner) have wide, bulky heads. But it's possible to find ones which are narrower relative to their, uh, maw, I guess you could call it? Example:

   [image]

   I suppose the same may apply for fixed-width wrenches/spanners, but that seems like overkill to invest in.
3. That image in the previous suggestion is from a page with many [tight-clearance tools](https://www.mcmaster.com/tight-clearance-wrenches/). I don't recommend any one of them specifically, nor the manufacturer (who may be good or bad, I've never used their tools before), but it has some more ideas of tools to consider, which you might then take to an actual store and look for something similar.